# Which one should I choose as my preferred graphic processor?

Tags: pc

I have a laptop with both a dedicated NVIDIA processor and an integrated Intel HD processor. When I go to make sure my games (for example SWTOR) are using the correct processor, I have a choice between "NVIDIA GPU" and "High Performance NVIDIA Processor" and "Integrated Graphics" . Obviously I'm not going to choose the integrated one, but which of the NVIDIA choices are best for running games?

Comment: If I understand this correctly, "NVIDIA GPU" is the dedicated graphics processor, while "High Performance NVIDIA processor" sounds more like the CPU, so this option would probably use one of your main CPU's cores for graphics. If you don't need the GPU for anything else, I would assume it's the best choice because then all CPU cores can be used for other stuff (which the game [engine] can handle on its own).

Comment: Does your laptop have two dedicated GPU's? As in, an SLI configuration? If not, either High Performance NVIDIA GPU or NVIDIA GPU should make no difference.

Comment: For anyone voting to close- *read the question as well as the title*. It's not about recommendation, it's about a configuration option.

Comment: Please post the model of your system so we can check what graphics cards it contains. (or maybe get it moved to somewhere with the correct support).

Comment: Where are you seeing these three choices? Are you getting all three choices from the same menu?

Comment: What laptop are you using? Please post the exact make/model

Comment: I agree with @scenia, You should use the GPU since it's the Graphics Processing Unit, The Central Processing Unit should be used for other processing, not necessarily gaming.  The GPU is being used with your graphics card, CPU is on the motherboard and is used for many things by default.  By choosing the CPU, you'd get less performance than the GPU since the CPU is already being used by a lot of different stuff.

Answer (score 1):

The "Nvidia GPU" choice shouldn't be here:

[Nvidia's documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/technologies/desktop/optimus.htm) about Optimus only mentions "Integrated" and "High Performance".

And a Google image search on `nvidia "preferred graphics processor"` returns countless results with those 2 options ("High-performance NVIDIA processor" and "Integrated graphics") and none with "NVIDIA GPU".

So, you should probably choose the "High-performance NVIDIA processor" option.

The extra "NVIDIA GPU" option may point to a driver problem.